# Absolute value of regulated function

Tags: calculus, limits

The task is to show that the absolute value of a regulated function is again a regulated function.

A regulated function is a function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

For every point in the interval $(a,b)$ exists a limit from both sides.

$$
f (x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} t_n(x)
$$

where $t_n(x)$ is a step function in the interval $(a,b)$

My current approaches was the following:

$$
|f(x)| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |t_n(x)|
$$

but I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: It seems you're done if you prove that  $|a_n|\to|a|$ whenever $a_n\to a$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Surely you mean : "there exist step functions $t_n$ such that $f(x) = \lim t_n(x)$". In that case, the idea that you have is correct, you only have to prove that $|a_n| \to |a|$ whenever $a_n \to a$. This should be obvious from definition.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses, but how would I document the proof of $|a_n| \rightarrow |a|$ for all $a_n \rightarrow a$?

Comment: This follows from the continuity of the absolute value.